# Unable to import cosmosDB packages in spark-shell

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to upload some data from dataframe to azure cosmosDB.

I have downloaded the below jar files and added to my local folder along with eventHub_Jars.

```
azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.3.3.jar
azure-cosmosdb-2.0.0.jar
azure-documentdb-1.16.4.jar
documentdb-bulkexecutor-2.4.1.jar
```

Below is the script i used to open the shell script which is working.

```
shell-script --master local --jars eventHub_Jars/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.3.3.jar
```

When I use the shell script along with eventHub jars  or other jars as

```
spark-shell --master local --packages com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.13 --jars eventHub_Jars/scala-library-2.11.12.jar, azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11-2.3.2.jar, azure-eventhubs-1.0.2.jar, proton-j-0.25.0.jar, scala-java8-compat_2.11-0.9.0.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar, azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.3.3.jar
```

Shell script is opening 
But when I try to import

```
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config
```

it is throwing the below error

```
error: object cosmosdb is not a member of package com.microsoft.azure
       import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config
```

what could be the reason for the above error.?
Is there any syntax issue? It seems like the only first jar added is working. If we try to import any package from any other jars, it will throw the above error!

Answer (score 1):

When I tried this I had an issue with the `--jars` option using the relative path to retrieve the jar files unless I added "file:///" to the start of the path where I had stored the jar files.
For example if a jar file was located in `/usr/local/spark/jars_added/` (a folder I created) the required path for the `--jars` option is `file:///usr/local/spark/jars_added/*.jar` where "*" represents your jar name.

The following won't be the same on your machine, however, you get the idea for specifying the jar files.

```
spark-shell 
--master local 
--packages com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.13 
--jars file:///usr/local/spark/jars_added/eventHub_Jars/scala-library-2.11.12.jar, 
file:///usr/local/spark/jars_added/azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11-2.3.2.jar, 
file:///usr/local/spark/jars_added/azure-eventhubs-1.0.2.jar, 
file:///usr/local/spark/jars_added/proton-j-0.25.0.jar, 
file:///usr/local/spark/jars_added/scala-java8-compat_2.11-0.9.0.jar, 
file:///usr/local/spark/jars_added/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar, 
file:///usr/local/spark/jars_added/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.3.3.jar
```

Alternatively, you can copy the jar files to the default location where jar files are retrieved for each spark session (note if you have a `jars` folder in `$SPARK_HOME` this will override the default location. In case readers are unsure the `$SPARK_HOME` is most likely equal to `/usr/local/spark`). On my machine jars are retrieved from `/usr/local/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.11/jars` by default for example.

Comment: I tried with providing full path of jar file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is working when I specify the full path for each jars after `--jars`

```
spark-shell --master local --packages com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.13 --jars eventHub_Jars/scala-library-2.11.12.jar,eventHub_Jars/azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11-2.3.2.jar,eventHub_Jars/azure-eventhubs-1.0.2.jar,eventHub_Jars/proton-j-0.25.0.jar,eventHub_Jars/scala-java8-compat_2.11-0.9.0.jar,eventHub_Jars/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar,eventHub_Jars/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.3.3.jar
```